# How to return calendar value to main component from the common file using angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using Angular8 + bootstrap date time picker. Here i am using reactive form, where in when i open the popup, date get binded into particular field in StartDate and endDate calendar date starts with the startDate. Here, as the same lines of code i am using in multiple components and places, so i am calling this method in common service file and calling that method in the component. But i get [object object] instead of getting date and the endDate calendar is not getting reset based on the value in startDate.
Please help me to solve this issue.

**TS (main component)**:

```
private startDate(date, restrictDate) {
    let setMinDate = date ? new DatePipe('en').transform(new Date(new Date(date).setDate(new Date(date).getDate() + 1)), 'MM/dd/yyyy') : new DatePipe('en').transform(new Date(), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
   let newDate = this.baseService.dateEvent('.startACHDate',true,setMinDate);
        this.achInfoForm.get('startDate').setValue(newDate, { emitEvent: false });
  }



 private endDate(date, boolValue) {
    let endMinDate = date ? date : new DatePipe('en').transform(new Date(), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
    let endDate = this.baseService.dateEvent('.endACHDate',true,endMinDate)
    this.endDateSet();
      this.achInfoForm.get('endDate').setValue(endDate, { emitEvent: false });
  }

  private endDateSet() {
    $(".endACHDate")
      .data("DateTimePicker")
      .minDate(this.achInfoForm.value.startDate);
  }
```

HTML:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control startACHDate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"
                        formControlName="startDate" autocomplete="off" (blur)="startDateBlur()">
 <input type="text" class="form-control endACHDate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"
                        id="endDateReason" formControlName="endDate" autocomplete="off"
                        (blur)="dateChanges('endDate', $event)">
```

Common.service.ts:

```
dateEvent(value,event,minDate) {
   return $(value).datetimepicker(
      {
        useCurrent: event,
        format: "L",
        minDate: minDate,
      }).on('dp.change', (e) => {
        const date = e.date.format('L');
        let newDate = date;
      });
  }
```

Comment: If you could format your code a bit better, it would help understand the problem. From what I understand, you are trying to bind data from the datepicker component with Angular, correct? I can't solve your problem but maybe this package can help https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview

Comment: Thanks for your response, here everything wors fine, provdided i paste codes of common.service.ts method instead of calling that method, but with taking that method from other file is creating issue, need help and also i cant use ng-bootstrap, i need this to get worked by using bootstrap-datetimepicker.